# Upload 32 & 64 APKs in Google Play Console after August 1st

Tags: android, flutter, apk, google-play-console

I am aware how to upload multiple apks in Google Play Console as [described in this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMl_oLlf_g0). 
This approach works so far.

However, I have my doubts it won't work anymore after August 1st, since Google Play Console won't accept 32 bit apk anymore and the current process as described in the above link is as follow:

- Create Release
- Upload 32 bit APK
- Save, Review and finally
- **Start Rollout to Production** - I suspect this step won't pass for 32 APK after August 1st
- Create Release
- Press **Retain** to keep 32 bit APK
- Start, Review and Start Rollout to Production

So my question is - if I would like to keep releasing 32 & 64 APK as alternative of apk bundle (which is Google Play Console preferable but not yet mandatory option), how shall I proceed so I can release 32 APK along with 64 one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload two APKs in the same release as long as the APK targeting 64-bit has a higher version code than the APK targeting 32-bit (Google Play will complain if you don't do that). All the documentation on this topic can be found at: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks

A simpler alternative is to upload a single Android App Bundle in place of an APK, and Google Play will take care of generating the APKs for each of the native architecture your app supports. The documentation can be found at: https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Comment: OK, just to make sure, I have got it right, the process above should look like: 1) create release; 2) upload both APK (whereas 32 one has a lower version code, than the 64 one); 3) Save, Review; 4) Start Rollout to Production. Is that how the process above should be amended?